# Android support library throwing a Resources Not Found exception

Tags: android, android-support-library

Received this crash report from a couple of users now. So far none have responded to my follow up emails asking what they were doing when the app crashed. Does this look familiar to anyone?

```
USER_COMMENT=
USER_CRASH_DATE=2013-02-11T16:45:01.000-06:00
PACKAGE_NAME=com.bandsintown
APP_VERSION_NAME=3.2.1
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2
PHONE_MODEL=Galaxy Nexus
STACK_TRACE=android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x10101
at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1668)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Yea, the stack trace has nothing in there regarding my app, instead it is just all related to the support library. I've experienced issues before where one crash causes a 2nd crash, and the 2nd crash is the one which ACRA reports. It could be a case of that. But I figured it would be worth asking here in case anyone else has seen it and found a universal solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you try to locate the resource ID in the generated `R` class?

Comment: The resId isn't in my app's R class, or any of my library projects' R classes. The support library is a jar, not a library project, so I can't search in the R class for that, unless there is a method someone could fill me in on.

Comment: I think its crashing inside one of your Fragment.. when android tries to load one of your fragment it fails and its throwing error.. usually when you set image..  setImageDrawable, setImageResources.. check for those calls and make sure you are parsing in proper R.id.myimag.. etc.

Comment: It would appear that the device the support library is running on is referencing an Android resource (for instance `@android:color/...`) that isn't there. I have read some time back about a problem on some Sony devices related to ListViews with `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`. It's probably unrelated, but might give you some insight into working around it.

Comment: Took me a while to find the post, but here it is: [Xperia devices do not work well with SherlockActionBar](https://plus.google.com/114227856179062761851/posts/ei71PSkxyBK)

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's probably what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:
Go to File Menu-> Open file-> browse your Project directory in workspace -> select the .classpath file openit->

Keep only below entries in this file and remove all others

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="your dir path without space.../extras/android/support /v4/android-support-v4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
 </classpath>
```

Save the file.
then in Eclipse-> Package Explorer ->right click Project -> Android tools -> Fix Project Properties.

This will add all required files to project , if you want to cross check open .classpath file again and check updates in it.

Run the project successfully :)